# Addressing AttributeError with except in for loop (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, attributeerror

New to Python but here is the code I'm using:

```
lst2 = list()
for i in lst1:
   try: 
      df1 = pd.DataFrame(i.QID1)
except AttributeError:
      "null"
df2 = lst2.append(df1)
```

lst2 is generating the output that I want, but the instances where i.QID1 does not exist are being populated by the data from the previous instance, instead of "null". I'm sure it's because of the 'except AttributeError' piece, just not sure how to fix it. As I say I'm a noob.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is off, and you didn't assign the "null" value to anything.

```
lst2 = list()
for i in lst1:
    try: 
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(i.QID1)
    except AttributeError:
        df1 = "null"
    lst2.append(df1)
```

- Everything has to be indented under the `for` loop if you want it to happen inside the loop.
- The `try` and `except` need to be at the same level of indentation.
- Appending `df1` to `lst2` doesn't return anything, so there's no point assigning it to `df2`.

Another way to build this list could be to write a function that returns the dataframe (or "null") for a given `i` and use that in a comprehension:

```
def dataframe_or_null(i):
    try: 
        return pd.DataFrame(i.QID1)
    except AttributeError:
        return "null"

lst2 = [dataframe_or_null(i) for i in lst1]
```